# Mongoosejs : Populate doesn't return any data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, meanjs

Hi I'm new in mongoose and I have a problem with ***populate collection*** it doesn't return any data, I don't know why here's my code:

**Company Model**

```
'use strict';

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema,
    Agent = mongoose.model('Agent'),
    DBRef = mongoose.SchemaTypes.DBRef;

/**
 * Company Schema
 */
var CompanySchema = new Schema({
name: {
    type: String,
    default: '',
    //required: 'Please fill Company name',
    trim: true
},
created: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
},
updated: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
},
address: {
    type: String,
    default: '',
    //required: 'Please fill Company address',
    trim: true
},
locked: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: true,
},
deleted: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false,
},
logo: {
    type: String,
    default: '',
},
email: {
    type: String,
    default: '', 
    index: { unique: true }
    //required: 'Please fill Company email',
},
tel: {
    type: String,
    default: '',
    //required: 'Please fill Company tel',
},
fax: {
    type: String,
    default: '',
    //required: 'Please fill Company fax',
},
type: {
    type: String,
    //required: 'Please fill Company type',
    trim: true
},
description: {
    type: String,
    default: '',
    trim: true
},
validator: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
},
admins: [Agent]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Company', CompanySchema);
```

**Agent Model**

```
'use strict';

/**
* Module dependencies.
*/
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
Schema = mongoose.Schema,
//Company = mongoose.model('Company'),
DBRef = mongoose.SchemaTypes.DBRef;

/**
 * Agent Schema
 */
var AgentSchema = new Schema({
// Agent model fields   
// ...
firstname: {
    type: String,
    default: ''
},
lastname: {
    type: String,
    default: ''
},
email: {
    type: String,
    default: '', 
    index: { unique: true }
},
password: {
    type: String,
    default: ''
},
roles: {
    type: Array,
},
created: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
},
updated: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
},
deleted: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
},
locked: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
},
workFor:  {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Company'
}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Agent', AgentSchema);
```

**Populate Code**

```
Company.findById(id).populate('admins').exec(function(err, company) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    if (!company) return next(new Error('Failed to load Company ' + id));
    console.log(company.admins);
    req.company = company ;
    next();
});
```

thanks :) .

Answer (score 0):

your schema definition of company actually defines that the agents are embedded into the company document, not referenced. If you want references that you then could populate you should use something like this:

```
var CompanySchema = new Schema({
....
admins: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Agent'}],
....
```

Comment: i do that but it doesn't give any reslut

Comment: well, your Schema and your query look correct (if you made the correction I suggested in the answer above). Maybe in your database you don't have company objects that contain ObjectIds of admins in the company.admins collection? did you check the contents of your DB beore this query? or show us the code where you save the company objects and the referenced admin objects.

Answer (score 0):

thnks reto, here is the saving code of company :

```
/**
* Create a Company
 */
exports.create = function(req, res) {
    var company = new Company(req.body);
    User.findById('54e22d19aae0cff01a47df96',function(err,user){
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).send({
                messages: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
            });
        }


        company.user = user;
        req.checkBody('name', 'please fill the name').notEmpty();
        req.checkBody('address', 'please fill the address').notEmpty();
        req.checkBody('tel', 'please fill a correct phone').notEmpty().isNumeric();
        req.checkBody('type', 'please fill the type').notEmpty();
        req.checkBody('email', 'please fill a correct email').isEmail();
        req.checkBody('admin.firstname', 'please fill the admin firstname').notEmpty();
        req.checkBody('admin.lastname', 'please fill the admin lastname').notEmpty();
        req.checkBody('admin.email', 'please fill a correct admin email').isEmail();
        req.checkBody('admin.password', 'please fill the admin password').notEmpty();

        var errors = req.validationErrors();

        if (errors) {
            return res.status(400).send({
                    messages: errors
                });
        }else{


            company.save(function(err) {
                if (err) {
                    return res.status(400).send({
                        messages: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
                    });
                } else {
                    var agents = preapareAgents(req,company);
                    Agent.create(agents,function(err){
                        if(err){
                            return res.status(400).send({
                                messages: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
                            });
                        }else{
                            res.jsonp({company: company, agents: agents});
                        }
                });

                }
            });

        }
    });


};
```

Comment: You are mixing up two different concepts 1.  subdocument, where the admins are part of the company-schema (and saved redundantly in each company) and 2. References, where admins are saved in a different collection and you save only references in the company objects. Only in the second case you need populate. Your initial schema and your saving code assume concept 1, your query code with populate assume concept 2. Both are fine, you just need to decide which one use.

Comment: Actually, I looked at your code again. I am not sure about your intentions, your saving code assumes that there is 1 agent per company, but your schema has an array. Should this call save a new company AND a new agent? If you want references only in the company schema, you need to save the agent first, and then replace the company.agents property with an array containing the _id of the already saved agent before you save the company

Comment: this is my model : one company have multiple agents and the agent is linkend to one company how i can represent this in mongoose, thnks.
NB : I want to store admin in deferent schema.

Comment: if you want to store the agents in a seperate schema, then you need to do that manually, don't expect too much magic from mongoose. 1. Store the agent and get back the _id of the stored agent: new Agent({name: 'bla',}).save(callback function) 2. in the callback function set the agent id on the company: company.agents = [agent._id]; 3. store the company that contains now the reference to the saved agent: company.save()

Comment: thinks  @Reto for helps

Comment: you are welcome, please consider accepting/upvoting any of the answers if they are helping you.